# cmd.exe error windows 7 the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click ok to close the application

Tags: windows-7, command-line, virus, cmd.exe

when i try to open the cmd.exe. a box pops up with the message of cmd.exe error windows 7  the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click ok to close the application.
my pc was infected with surabaya virus and rootkit and removed it with Avast free anti virus and malwarebytes, spybot, but after this i am unable to open some files like windows defender and some system files.

Comment: It sounds like the tools improperly removed the infection.  Without access to a command prompt your problem cannot be solved.  The only real solution is to install a fresh instance Windows.

Comment: if you have configured system backup and restore,try to do the restore with the latest version of the backup which would give the error-free installation

Comment: Find if conhost.exe present in system32 or syswow64 folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have read this began for some users after a Windows Update in Nov 2014. It seems to be a conflict with Geforce Experience (Nvidia graphics cards) and the Win Update. 
Uninstalling Geforce experience has worked for many people. Perhaps Nividia are aware of the issue and have released a new driver by now - worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

if it happens for all programs there is something wrong with your registry and you must see this link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux3iMvyS7to

otherwise, follow these steps

Go to Start and type msconfig

Right-click and select System Configuration

Select the Service tab and click Hide all Microsoft Services then click Disable all.

Click Startup tab within the System Configuration dialog box.

Select Open Task Manager

Within the Startup tab of Task Manager, select Disable for each Startup item, then close Task Manager.

Click OK on the Startup tab of System Configuration.

Restart your computer.

hope it helps